# unity scrollRect not scrolling to the end via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scrollview

Its a basic question and I tried many methods and those solutions are not working.

I want to make a scrollView scroll to the end via script. Methods I have tried so far :

```
public ScrollRect myScrollRect;

public Scrollbar newScrollBar;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    //Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();

    //myScrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition = 0f;

    myScrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition = 0f;
    //myScrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition = 0.5f;

    //myScrollRect.normalizedPosition = new Vector2(0, 1);

    //Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();

    //myScrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition = Mathf.Clamp(myScrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition, 0f, 1f);

    Debug.Log("attached and everything is okay..");

}
```

I tried with different values also but in play mode it stays same and doesn't get to the end.

How can I make the scrollView scroll to the end via script and what I'm missing here?

Also heres a screenshot :
[image]
another screen-shot:
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: where did you attach your component?

Comment: In scrollView and reference to the scrollrect is also the scrollView.

Comment: `myScrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition` should do it. I see it commented out in your code. Are you sure you tried it? Your Unity version?

Comment: added another screenshot, here it is tried again. It needs to show the button at the end of the image. but myScrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition not scrolling it.